# is END OF FILE (EOF) right after the end of text or depends on the compiler?

Tags: c, file

I just started learning files in c few days ago. In order to understand how to manipulate correctly the functions, I wrote a code who create a new file (w+) read a string and using fputs() put it in the file. Using a function it find how many characters are there. the problem is if I don't rewind before calling the function, the output returned is very large compared to the string the output+string is exactly 4096 every time no matter how big the array. I don't understand why it should just return 0 if I don't rewind the pointer, and why it doesn't return 4096 when I rewind it, instead it returns the correct answer. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int daft(FILE* f){
    int s=0,c;
    while((c=fgetc(f))!=EOF){
        if(!isspace(c))
        s++;
    }
    return s;
}
int main(){
    char *ch;
    ch=malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("test.txt","w+");
    if(f!=NULL){
        gets(ch);
        fputs(ch,f);
        printf("n= %d\n",daft(f));
        fclose(f);
        
    }
    free(ch);
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is an UB. fgetc() simply returns EOF in that case.

Comment: You need to be aware of the fact that your learning material is outdated. `main()` is not the right syntax to define the main function since 2011, and it was discouraged and deprecated for longer still. Likewise `gets()` is not a part of C since 2011, and it was deprecated well before that. You want to [enable compiler warnings and treat them as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756). Beware of Microsoft C, it is an old compiler and Microsoft has no intention of bringing it up to modern standards (they are only interested in C++).

Comment: Note that [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/15168)

Answer (score 2):

You need to flush the stream after writing and before reading:

> **7.21.5.3 The fopen function**
> ...
> 7     When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the
> above list of `mode` argument values), both input and output may be performed on the
> associated stream. ***However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an
> intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`,
> `fsetpos`, or `rewind`)***, and input shall not be directly followed by output without an
> intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file. Opening (or creating) a text file with update mode may instead open (or create) a
> binary stream in some implementations.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis added.  By not flushing after writing and by not rewinding, the stream is not in a good state to be read from.  You've entered the realm of undefined behavior - `fgetc` returns *something* that's not `EOF` for many iterations, and as a result `s` is incremented to a very large value.

This is why it worked when you used the `rewind` function, because you reset the stream to be in a good state for reading.

Answer (score 1):

`EOF` is not necessarily stored in the file. Usually, files does not. It is what the function returns when it fails to read.

Also, [never use gets()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/6699433)

Comment: Older Microsoft text files do contain the EOF marker `0x1A` and if that character is read by `fgetc()` the function returns the  `EOF` flag `-1` even if it is not at the end of the file.

Comment: understood, but is the difference in the output is because I used gets()?

Comment: also when does the function fails to read? is it right after of the characters end? I just don't understand why it gives me different output when I don't use `rewind`